# Model not found: ' ' using odoo in kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, containers, odoo, odoo-12

```
 
Model not found: openg2p.disbursement.batch.transaction
 
Error context:
View `openg2p.disbursement.batch.transaction.form`
[view_id: 789, xml_id: n/a, model: openg2p.disbursement.batch.transaction, parent_id: n/a]
None" while parsing /opt/bitnami/odoo/addons/openg2p_disbursement_advice/views/openg2p_disbursement_batch_transaction.xml:4, near
<record id="view_openg2p_disbursement_batch_transaction_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">openg2p.disbursement.batch.transaction.form</field>
            <field name="model">openg2p.disbursement.batch.transaction</field>
```

I'm facing this issue while installing a module in odoo v12. It is running in IBM Cluster. I used bitnami helm chart for odoo v12. The same module is getting installed in my local as well as cloud without facing any issues. I can't figure out what is wrong. The manifests ordering and init ordering are correct.
Full Stack Trace : https://pastebin.com/hFS4ybvh.
Manifest file for reference:

```
"data": [
        "data/openg2p_disbursement_advice_data.xml",
        "security/openg2p_banks_security.xml",
        "security/ir.model.access.csv",
        "views/openg2p_beneficiary.xml",
        "views/openg2p_disbursement_advice.xml",
        "views/openg2p_disbursement_advice_line.xml",
        "views/openg2p_disbursement_advice_report.xml",
        "views/openg2p_disbursement_batch.xml",
        "views/openg2p_disbursement_slip.xml",
        "views/openg2p_registration.xml",
        "views/report_disbursement_advice.xml",
        "views/report_disbursementslip.xml",
        "views/report_disbursementslipdetails.xml",
        "views/res_bank.xml",
        "views/res_partner_bank.xml",
        "views/openg2p_gateway_transaction.xml",
        "views/action_menu.xml",
        "views/transaction_menu.xml",
        "views/openg2p_disbursement_single_transaction.xml",
        "views/openg2p_disbursement_batch_transaction.xml",
        "views/openg2p_disbursement_main.xml",
        "views/openg2p_disbursement_file.xml",
    ],
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Check __init__.py file in models and see if you import the py file , also check __init__.py in module folder and make sure the models is imported

Comment: Yes it is imported in both init files.